# Extracting messages by format from text

Tags: python, regex, perl, awk, sed

I have a bunch of data which looks like this:

```
|ApplVerID=9|unknownID_9=184|MessageType=X|SenderCompID=CME|MsgSeqNum=131523|SendingTime=20140915014116175|TradeDate=20140915|NoMDEntries=1|MDUpdateAction=0|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=951806|RptSeq=3|SecurityDesc=UD:1T: SG 0822951806|MDEntryType=2|MDEntryPx=21|MDEntrySize=1|MDEntryTime=14116000|TradeCondition=E|NetChgPrevDay=1|TradeID=1|TradeVolume=5|AggressorSide=2|MatchEventIndicator=1|unknownID_10=224
|ApplVerID=9|unknownID_9=272|MessageType=X|SenderCompID=CME|MsgSeqNum=131524|SendingTime=20140915014116175|TradeDate=20140915|NoMDEntries=2|MDUpdateAction=0|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=265872|RptSeq=7|SecurityDesc=ONX4 P3400|MDEntryType=2|MDEntryPx=17|MDEntrySize=1|MDEntryTime=14116000|TradeCondition=1|NetChgPrevDay=0|TradeID=1|TradeVolume=1|AggressorSide=2|MDUpdateAction=0|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=311863|RptSeq=8|SecurityDesc=ONX4 C4700|MDEntryType=2|MDEntryPx=9|MDEntrySize=1|MDEntryTime=14116000|TradeCondition=1|NetChgPrevDay=0|TradeID=1|TradeVolume=1|AggressorSide=2|unknownID_10=160
|ApplVerID=9|unknownID_9=411|MessageType=X|SenderCompID=CME|MsgSeqNum=131574|SendingTime=20140915020404771|TradeDate=20140915|NoMDEntries=4|MDUpdateAction=0|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=873267|RptSeq=16|SecurityDesc=ONX4 P3600|MDEntryType=2|MDEntryPx=30|MDEntrySize=7|MDEntryTime=20404000|TickDirection=2|TradeCondition=E|NetChgPrevDay=-5|TradeID=1|TradeVolume=5|AggressorSide=1|MatchEventIndicator=1|MDUpdateAction=1|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=873267|RptSeq=17|SecurityDesc=ONX4 P3600|MDEntryType=1|MDEntryPx=45|MDEntrySize=3|MDEntryTime=20404000|TradingSessionID=2|NumberOfOrders=1|MDPriceLevel=1|MDUpdateAction=0|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=873267|RptSeq=18|SecurityDesc=ONX4 P3600|MDEntryType=7|MDEntryPx=41|MDEntryTime=20404000|MDUpdateAction=0|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=873267|RptSeq=19|SecurityDesc=ONX4 P3600|MDEntryType=8|MDEntryPx=45|MDEntryTime=20404000|unknownID_10=043
```

I want to extract every message which contains an 'MDEntryType=2'.  Note, there can be multiple messages in each line.  The number of messages is indicated in 'NoMDEntries'.  There are other irrelevant messages, such as the one with 'MDEntryType=7' above.   Each inidividual message I want starts with 'MDUpdateAction=' and ends just before the next 'MDUpdateAction=' or with 'unknownID_10='.

Note, there is one 'SendingTime' per block.

I'd like to return the data in the following format:

```
|SendingTime=20140915014116175|MDUpdateAction=0|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=951806|RptSeq=3|SecurityDesc=UD:1T: SG 0822951806|MDEntryType=2|MDEntryPx=21|MDEntrySize=1|MDEntryTime=14116000|TradeCondition=E|NetChgPrevDay=1|TradeID=1|TradeVolume=5|AggressorSide=2|MatchEventIndicator=1|
|SendingTime=20140915014116175|MDUpdateAction=0|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=265872|RptSeq=7|SecurityDesc=ONX4 P3400|MDEntryType=2|MDEntryPx=17|MDEntrySize=1|MDEntryTime=14116000|TradeCondition=1|NetChgPrevDay=0|TradeID=1|TradeVolume=1|AggressorSide=2|
|SendingTime=20140915014116175|MDUpdateAction=0|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=311863|RptSeq=8|SecurityDesc=ONX4 C4700|MDEntryType=2|MDEntryPx=9|MDEntrySize=1|MDEntryTime=14116000|TradeCondition=1|NetChgPrevDay=0|TradeID=1|TradeVolume=1|AggressorSide=2|
|SendingTime=20140915020404771|MDUpdateAction=0|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=873267|RptSeq=16|SecurityDesc=ONX4 P3600|MDEntryType=2|MDEntryPx=30|MDEntrySize=7|MDEntryTime=20404000|TickDirection=2|TradeCondition=E|NetChgPrevDay=-5|TradeID=1|TradeVolume=5|AggressorSide=1|MatchEventIndicator=1|
```

If it is too difficult to have the sending time at the beginning of each line, you can leave that off.  I'll just separate the data by day, and use the milliseond recorded in 'MDEntryTime'.

I am happy to work with any software solution that works (sed, perl, etc.).  I have been trying to solve this with Emacs macros to no avail.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

EDIT:  There are some lines with two instances of 'MDEntryType=2', and so there are two messages to extract from the line.  For example:

```
|ApplVerID=9|unknownID_9=293|MessageType=X|SenderCompID=CME|MsgSeqNum=153770|SendingTime=20140915113751112|TradeDate=20140915|NoMDEntries=2|MDUpdateAction=0|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=292861|RptSeq=6|SecurityDesc=ONZ4 P4100|MDEntryType=2|MDEntryPx=151|MDEntrySize=6|MDEntryTime=113751000|TickDirection=2|TradeCondition=1|NetChgPrevDay=-12|TradeID=1|TradeVolume=5|AggressorSide=1|MDUpdateAction=0|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=726692|RptSeq=7|SecurityDesc=ONV4 P4100|MDEntryType=2|MDEntryPx=276|MDEntrySize=5|MDEntryTime=113751000|TickDirection=2|TradeCondition=1|NetChgPrevDay=-13|TradeID=1|TradeVolume=5|AggressorSide=2|unknownID_10=153
```

In general, any line can have an arbitrary number of messages to extract and messages to discard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Perl solution that iterates over all of the fields in each record and maintains a state in variables `$st` (the *sending time*), `$nm` (the *number of messages*), `$etype` (the current message's *entry type*) and array `@message` (the current *message contents*)

Fields are added to `@message` until the start of the next message or `unknownID_10` is seen, when the contents of the message, together with the saved sending time, is printed to the output and `@message` is emptied

This example reads directly from the program source file itself using the `DATA` file handle. I trust that you can write the code to open and read from a separate input file? If you just want to specify the input file on the command line then you can change `<DATA>` to `<>` and everything will work for you

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

while ( <DATA> ) {

    chomp;
    my @fields = /[^|\s]+/g;

    my ( $st, $nm, $etype );
    my @message;

    for my $f ( @fields ) {

        if ( $f =~ /SendingTime/ ) {
            $st = $f;
        }
        elsif ( $f =~ /NoMDEntries=(\d+)/ ) {
            $nm = $1;
        }
        elsif ( $f =~ /MDUpdateAction|unknownID_10/ ) {
            if ( @message and defined $etype and $etype == 2 ) {
                print "|", join("|", $st, @message), "|\n";
            }
            @message = ($f);
            $etype = undef;
        }
        elsif ( defined $nm ) {
            $etype = $1 if $f =~ /MDEntryType=(\d+)/;
            push @message, $f;
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
|ApplVerID=9|unknownID_9=184|MessageType=X|SenderCompID=CME|MsgSeqNum=131523|SendingTime=20140915014116175|TradeDate=20140915|NoMDEntries=1|MDUpdateAction=0|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=951806|RptSeq=3|SecurityDesc=UD:1T: SG 0822951806|MDEntryType=2|MDEntryPx=21|MDEntrySize=1|MDEntryTime=14116000|TradeCondition=E|NetChgPrevDay=1|TradeID=1|TradeVolume=5|AggressorSide=2|MatchEventIndicator=1|unknownID_10=224
|ApplVerID=9|unknownID_9=272|MessageType=X|SenderCompID=CME|MsgSeqNum=131524|SendingTime=20140915014116175|TradeDate=20140915|NoMDEntries=2|MDUpdateAction=0|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=265872|RptSeq=7|SecurityDesc=ONX4 P3400|MDEntryType=2|MDEntryPx=17|MDEntrySize=1|MDEntryTime=14116000|TradeCondition=1|NetChgPrevDay=0|TradeID=1|TradeVolume=1|AggressorSide=2|MDUpdateAction=0|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=311863|RptSeq=8|SecurityDesc=ONX4 C4700|MDEntryType=2|MDEntryPx=9|MDEntrySize=1|MDEntryTime=14116000|TradeCondition=1|NetChgPrevDay=0|TradeID=1|TradeVolume=1|AggressorSide=2|unknownID_10=160
|ApplVerID=9|unknownID_9=411|MessageType=X|SenderCompID=CME|MsgSeqNum=131574|SendingTime=20140915020404771|TradeDate=20140915|NoMDEntries=4|MDUpdateAction=0|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=873267|RptSeq=16|SecurityDesc=ONX4 P3600|MDEntryType=2|MDEntryPx=30|MDEntrySize=7|MDEntryTime=20404000|TickDirection=2|TradeCondition=E|NetChgPrevDay=-5|TradeID=1|TradeVolume=5|AggressorSide=1|MatchEventIndicator=1|MDUpdateAction=1|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=873267|RptSeq=17|SecurityDesc=ONX4 P3600|MDEntryType=1|MDEntryPx=45|MDEntrySize=3|MDEntryTime=20404000|TradingSessionID=2|NumberOfOrders=1|MDPriceLevel=1|MDUpdateAction=0|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=873267|RptSeq=18|SecurityDesc=ONX4 P3600|MDEntryType=7|MDEntryPx=41|MDEntryTime=20404000|MDUpdateAction=0|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=873267|RptSeq=19|SecurityDesc=ONX4 P3600|MDEntryType=8|MDEntryPx=45|MDEntryTime=20404000|unknownID_10=043
```

#### output

```
|SendingTime=20140915014116175|MDUpdateAction=0|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=951806|RptSeq=3|SecurityDesc=UD:1T: SG 0822951806|MDEntryType=2|MDEntryPx=21|MDEntrySize=1|MDEntryTime=14116000|TradeCondition=E|NetChgPrevDay=1|TradeID=1|TradeVolume=5|AggressorSide=2|MatchEventIndicator=1|
|SendingTime=20140915014116175|MDUpdateAction=0|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=265872|RptSeq=7|SecurityDesc=ONX4 P3400|MDEntryType=2|MDEntryPx=17|MDEntrySize=1|MDEntryTime=14116000|TradeCondition=1|NetChgPrevDay=0|TradeID=1|TradeVolume=1|AggressorSide=2|
|SendingTime=20140915014116175|MDUpdateAction=0|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=311863|RptSeq=8|SecurityDesc=ONX4 C4700|MDEntryType=2|MDEntryPx=9|MDEntrySize=1|MDEntryTime=14116000|TradeCondition=1|NetChgPrevDay=0|TradeID=1|TradeVolume=1|AggressorSide=2|
|SendingTime=20140915020404771|MDUpdateAction=0|SecurityIDSource=8|SecurityID=873267|RptSeq=16|SecurityDesc=ONX4 P3600|MDEntryType=2|MDEntryPx=30|MDEntrySize=7|MDEntryTime=20404000|TickDirection=2|TradeCondition=E|NetChgPrevDay=-5|TradeID=1|TradeVolume=5|AggressorSide=1|MatchEventIndicator=1|
```

Comment: This looks perfect!  Thanks.  The data are in local files (~4GB each) which I have been piping into sed scripts with cat and directing output to local files with `>`.  I am happy to write something to pipe the data into your script, but in what language is your script written, perl?

Comment: @MattBrigida: Yes, this is Perl. All you need to do is write `perl etype2.pl infile.txt > outfile.txt` where `etype2.pl` is the name of the Perl source file

Comment: By the way, both sed and perl (and a huge majority of command-line utilities) will accept input file parameters, and there is no need to pipe into them from cat. See [*The Useless Use of Cat Award*](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#uucaletter)

Comment: Got it working!  Thanks again.  Your help is really appreciated.  And thanks for the link to the cat award -- a good (and funny) way to help people like me be more proper at the command line.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

I only output two fields add the rest yourself in the order you need.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} /MDEntryType=2/ {print $7,$10}' file1 

SendingTime=20140915014116175|MDUpdateAction=0
SendingTime=20140915014116175|MDUpdateAction=0
SendingTime=20140915020404771|MDUpdateAction=0
```

if you have few fields to report listing them one by one as $7,$10,... etc is best.  If you're printing almost all there might be better options.

I misunderstood your question and after edit it became more clear.  However, your input/output sample is too detailed without adding any value.  I set up a simpler case with the essence of the problem you're trying to solve.

I'm ignoring the filtering requirement since pattern matching is already addressed above.

Assuming you have the record structure like this

```
P1 PA1 PA2 C C1 C2 C3 C C1 C2 C3 C C1 C2 C3
```

there is a parent with attributes and children sub records with header fields C and attributes C1,C2,C3

```
$ awk '{mtc=FS "C" FS; 
        n=split($0,a,mtc); 
        for(i=2;i<=n;i++) 
            print a[1] mtc a[i]}' file
```

we define the a break point based on the Child header field (prefix and suffix with field separators), split the record based on this value and print parent-child pairs on separate lines

```
P1 PA1 PA2 C C1 C2 C3
P1 PA1 PA2 C C1 C2 C3
P1 PA1 PA2 C C1 C2 C3
```

You further want to extract only a subset of parent attributes, let's say the second one, here we can use `awk` again, but as an alternative I'll use `cut`
We want all the fields except first and third, that is

```
$ awk ... | cut -d' ' -f1,3 --complement
```

will give you the result

```
PA1 C C1 C2 C3
PA1 C C1 C2 C3
PA1 C C1 C2 C3
```

for your example FS will be `|`, and child header will be `MDUpdateAction=0`.

Comment: Thanks !  This is great.  Is there an easy was to have it work if there are two instances of 'MDEntryType=2' on one line?  My example unfortunately only has one per line, but there are many lines in the data with two.  I'll add an example to the question above.

Comment: Yes it will look for the first match, doesn't matter how many more matches there are.  However, each line will be treated as one record.  This won't split it into two.

Comment: I am trying to pull data on all the matches.  So if there are three matches, it returns three sets of 'MDEntryPx' and so forth.  If you say it will do this, I am happy to dive in to the awk manual.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: If your requirements are more complex it's better to start with `awk` where you'll have more control on transform and extract with a clean syntax.  It's not clear what you do when you have more than one record group.   Your 3rd input line supposed to have 7 but the output only has one.  If you can create a clean input/output pair with the essence of your  need without ugly details more answers you'll get as Yoda says...

Comment: This is a dreadful answer; it barely begins to answer the question. All it does is extract the `SendingTime` field and the first field of the first message, and makes no attempt to unpack each record into a number of messages as described in the question. It also doesn't explain how to handle messages with varying numbers of fields. I'm afraid you'll have to try a little harder than that

Comment: @Borodin, I might have misunderstood the problem (perhaps became more clear after the edit) but I think you misunderstood the concept of SO.  It's not a free programming service.